# How to see content inside div tags in apex page?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, apex-code

Locationbox is an external system that services like google maps. You can review an example here;

http://www.locationbox.com.tr/web/demo/displaymap.jsp

I want to deploy it to salesforce platform.
First script tag retrieves javascript code from locationbox service. After working startup(), it sets a dynamic content to ***div id="map"...*** in document. There are several png images in the dynamic content. The code below works locally as html files but it doesn't work in apex page. (the function x() works as expected in apex page.)

I am using the following code in apex page.

```
<apex:page>
    <script language="Javascript" src="http://www.locationbox.com.tr/locationbox/services?Key=mykey&Cmd=API&Typ=JS"<script language="JavaScript">

        var mapper  = new IMapper();
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {alert('OK1'); x();}, false);
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {alert('OK1'); startup();}, false);

        function startup() {
            mapper.initMap(41.1, 29.1, 7);
            mapper.addNavigationPanel();
            MVGlobalVariables();
            return;
        }
        function x() {
            document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = 2;
        }
    </script>

    <div id="map" style="border: 1px solid black; width:100%; height:100%; z-index: 0; position:relative; -moz-user-select:none;   background-color: lightgrey;" tabindex="0">1</div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: 1. Can you try moving your `<div>` before the script? I see that you're attaching onload listeners but still it might help if you're sure the DOM object was known before the script fired. Also - their original example uses `body onload` 2. Remove `alerts()`, they might lead to some race-condition weird debugging issues. 3. Examine the requests & responses with Firebug or similar tool, maybe the service is returning some errors that you can see in console?

Comment: I have moved the '<div>' before the script code but it did not change. There is already body tags as default in apex page, no need to write again, I know so it is. Therefore, I used the alert to make sure it works correctly. I have not encountered any error that is returning from service, when I used Firebug. The problem may be caused by own Salesforce.
Do you have any other suggestions?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `apex:includeScript` right after your `apex:page` definition and not including  the locationbox-script as html-tag:

```salesforce
<apex:page>

<apex:includeScript value="http://www.locationbox.com.tr/locationbox/services?Key=mykey&Cmd=API&Typ=JS" />

...

</apex:page>
```

And for the best way try to use `https` link

Comment: I try to apex:includeScript as you said also I use Static Resource as following: `<apex:includeScript value="http://www.locationbox.com.tr/locationbox/services?Key=mykey&Cmd=API&Typ=‌​JS"/>` `<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.LocationboxJS}"/>`
The completion of that set up SSL certificate had been told LocationBox service team previously. They completed installation but https binding is not working properly. Therefore I use http binding. Could the problem be caused from it?